# Can't infer register for "RunStop" because its behavior does not match any supported register model ( Quartus II )

Tags: vhdl

Errors: 10821,10822...and many more..please help..(separate module)

> Error (10821): HDL error at AxisCounter.vhd(48): can't infer register for "RunStop" because its behavior does not match any supported register model
>   Error (10821): HDL error at AxisCounter.vhd(39): can't infer register for "RunStop" because its behavior does not match any supported register model
>   Error (10821): HDL error at AxisCounter.vhd(38): can't infer register for "RunStop" because its behavior does not match any supported register model
>   Error (10822): HDL error at AxisCounter.vhd(35): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge
>   Error (10822): HDL error at AxisCounter.vhd(38): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge
>   Error (12152): Can't elaborate user hierarchy "AxisCounter:\Check:0:AxisCounter_X"
>   Error: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 6 errors, 9  warnings
>       Error: Peak virtual memory: 486 megabytes
>       Error: Processing ended: Sun May 22 18:19:32 2016
>       Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:01
>       Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
>       Error (293001): Quartus II Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 8 errors, 9 warnings

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity AxisCounter is
    Port ( 
              BASECLK_IN      :  in   STD_LOGIC;
             START_STOP     :  in   STD_LOGIC;
             RESET_COUNT        :  in   STD_LOGIC;
              DIVISOR           :  in   Integer ;
              STEPS             :  in   Integer ;
             COUNT_STATUS   :  out  STD_LOGIC;
           AXISCLK_OUT      :  out  STD_LOGIC ;
              STEPSOVER         :  out  Integer);
end AxisCounter ;

architecture Behavioral of AxisCounter is
-- signals, variables and constants
   signal cnt_r         : Integer := 0 ;
   signal steps_r   : Integer := 0 ;
   signal blink_o   : std_logic := '0' ;
   signal RunStop   : std_logic := '1' ;
   --signal Compare1    : Integer := 75000000;  -- 1000000 ;
   --signal Steps1     : Integer := 12 ;

begin

  process(BASECLK_IN,RESET_COUNT,START_STOP) 
  begin
     if (START_STOP' event and START_STOP = '1') then
        RunStop <= '1';
     end if ;
    if rising_edge(BASECLK_IN) then
        if (RESET_COUNT = '0') then
            steps_r <= 0 ;
            cnt_r   <= DIVISOR ;
       elsif (RunStop = '1')then -- counter enabled
           cnt_r <= cnt_r - 1;
            if (cnt_r > (DIVISOR/2)) then
                blink_o <= '1' ;
            else
                blink_o <= '0' ;
                if (cnt_r = 0) then
                    steps_r <= steps_r + 1 ;
                    STEPSOVER <= steps_r ;
                    if (steps_r = STEPS) then
                        RunStop <= '0' ;
                    else
                        cnt_r <= DIVISOR ;
                    end if ;
                end if ;
            end if ;
        else
            blink_o <= '0' ;
        end if ;
    end if ;
  end process;


  AXISCLK_OUT <= blink_o ;
  COUNT_STATUS <= RunStop ;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: There is a certain style you have to use when coding a HDL_ for synthesis. You are not using it. You get different error messages, but your problem is the same as that of this questioner. Have a look at my answer[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539962/errorxst827-signal-count-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description/36543625#36543625) (goodness knows why my answer was downvoted - I teach VHDL for a living and do know what I'm talking about).

Comment: SO has a few *Error (10821): HDL error* questions over the years answered by attestation (it's difficult referencing Altera documentation long term) and answers don't assuage further questions. Suggested coding styles for registers are found in *Recommended HDL Coding Styles*, the section on *Register and Latch Coding Guidelines*, of Quartus Handbook Vol 1 *Design and Synthesis* or authoritatively  in *IEEE Std 1076.6-2004* (RTL Synthesis, now withdrawn) *6. Modeling hardware elements*, *6.1 Edge-sensitive sequential logic*. RunStop has two different clocks there may be more errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is for a flipflop to be created for RunStop that has to be clocked by two distinct clock signals: BASECLK_IN and START_STOP

There are multiple solutions for this problem:

1. you can define the behaviour of RunStop in such a way that it's no longer clocked by two sources
2. Create two versions of RunStop, 1 for each clock and combine them (asynchronously) at a later point.

Comment: But the same codes are synthesizable for Xilinx Spartan-6 device...How...??  Using Altera DE2 Cyclone II device having errors n problems.

Comment: Different devices can have different hardware building blocks available. For instance, the Xilinx device might have a form of latch available that can handle 2 clock inputs. This would mean that the hardware you described with your code can be synthesized.    The altera device does not have this building block available and quartus cannot synthesize the behaviour you described