# VHDL clocked LED Sequence

Tags: vhdl, clock, led

this is my first post on this site,
im studying VHDL for my Electronics degree and have to write a program that changes an LED sequence at each clock pulse for one sequence. i think i have cracked it but this is my first time using the VHDL language so im not sure if iv used the most efficient method. my code is.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity REG_LED is
 PORT(CLK:      IN  std_logic;              -- CLK input
     LEDS:      Out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0):= "11111"); -- initialise      output
End REG_LED;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF REG_LED IS
 SIGNAL Temp:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0):= "0000"; -- initailise comparison signal
  BEGIN
    CLK_0_Process:  PROCESS (CLK)   -- begin 
    BEGIN 
    if Temp <= "0000" Then          -- State 0          
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "0001" ;
            LEDS <= "00001";    
        END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "0001" Then  -- State 1
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "0010" ;
            LEDS <= "00001";
     END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "0010" Then  -- State 2
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "0011" ;
            LEDS <= "11111";
     END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "0011" Then  -- State 3  
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "0100" ;
            LEDS <= "00000";
     END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "0100" Then  -- State 4
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "0101" ;
            LEDS <= "11111";
     END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "0101" Then  -- State 5
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "0110" ;
            LEDS <= "00100";
     END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "0110" Then  -- State 6
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "0111" ;
            LEDS <= "01010";
     END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "0111" Then  -- State 7
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
            Temp <= "1000" ;
            LEDS <= "10001";
     END IF;
     ELSIF Temp <= "1000" Then  -- State 8
        if rising_edge(CLK) Then
                LEDS <= "10001";
     END IF;
    END IF;
    END PROCESS ;
END behavioral;
```

can anyone let me know if there is an alternative route that iv missed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd say it's an inefficient method, but, just like with any language, the more you learn the more efficient the code you are able to write. More importantly, you code is not *synthesisable*: you would not be able to produce hardware directly from it.

If you want your code to be *synthesisable*, you should stick to a template. Here is one such template for sequential logic with no asynchronous reset, which all synthesis tools should understand:

```
process(CLK)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    -- never put anything here
    if rising_edge(CLK) then  -- or falling_edge(CLK)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

So, you need to refactor your code to fit this template, ie something along the lines of:

```
process(CLK)
begin
  if rising_edge(CLK) then
    if Temp <= "0000" Then          -- State 0          
      Temp <= "0001" ;
      LEDS <= "00001";    
    ELSIF Temp <= "0001" Then  -- State 1
      Temp <= "0010" ;
      LEDS <= "00001";
    ELSIF Temp <= "0010" Then  -- State 2

    -- etc etc

    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

It seeing that `Temp` is just counting, it would be much more efficient (in terms of elegance of solution and fewer lines of code) to use the line `Temp <= Temp + 1;` in your code and to drive the `LEDS` signal using a `case` statement (in a separate process). But then you'd have to learn about *type conversion* and the `numeric_std` package and `case` statements, which presumably you haven't learnt about yet.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your reply, i have programmed in assembly and touched on C before but this really is about week 3 of VHDL so im still trying to get my head around it, what worse is this module is a self study module with limited lecturer input which is not ideal when learning a new programming language but hey thats why degrees are hard to obtain right. if you dont mid what makes the code un-synthesis-able? i only ask as when i simulated using ,modelsim the wave simulation showed an output for each clock state as expected. your correct with the Temp signal this

Comment: ~The temp signal is there just as marker so the sequence knows what position in the sequence the program is at and then can determine the next state in the sequence.  we have touched on case statements but i think i need to do more reading on the case statements and numeric_std package, i am looking to make this more elegant as it does look very cumbersome the program in its current form

Comment: A key point is that VHDL is not really a _programming_ language, it is a _hardware description_ language; its function is to _describe_ hardware, either just for simulation or to be _synthesised_ into hardware. Pretty much anything will simulate, but if you want to synthesise it, you need to restrict yourself to a subset of VHDL and restrict yourself to a certain style, the template I gave being part of that style.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539962/errorxst827-signal-count-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description/36543625#36543625).

Comment: THanks again Matt see my answer below, sorry still getting used to this forum

Comment: Thanks Matt sorry new to this forum i have posted the new question as advised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130851/vhdl-clocked-led-sequence-part-2