# VHDL clocked LED Sequence Part 2

Tags: vhdl, clock, led

I have to write a program that changes an LED sequence at each clock pulse for one sequence.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity REG_LED is
 PORT(CLK:      IN  std_logic;              -- CLK input
 LEDS:      Out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0):= "11111"); -- initialise output
End REG_LED;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF REG_LED IS
 SIGNAL Temp:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0):= "0000"; -- initailise comparison signal
BEGIN

CLK_Process:    PROCESS (CLK)   -- begin 
BEGIN 

if rising_edge(CLK) Then
       Temp <= Temp + 1 ;   
END IF;

iF TEMP > "1000" THEN
    Temp <= "XXXX";
End IF;

END PROCESS ;

LED_PROCESS: Process (Temp) --

BEGIN

    Case Temp is

        When "0000" =>
            LEDS <= "11111";
        When "0001" =>
            LEDS <= "00001";
        When "0010" =>
            LEDS <= "00001";
        When "0011" =>
            LEDS <= "11111";
        When "0100" =>
            LEDS <= "00000";
        When "0101" =>
            LEDS <= "11111";
        When "0110" =>
            LEDS <= "00100";
        When "0111" =>
            LEDS <= "01010";
        When "1000" =>
            LEDS <= "10001";
        When others => 
            LEDS <= "10001";
    End Case;               

End Process;
END behavioral;
```

Does this look more like what you would expect? it simulates but i cant test the synthesis of the code as i have now hardware to test it with. Or if there is a way because I'm new to VHDL I haven't worked out how to test it.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity REG_LED is
PORT(CLK:       IN  std_logic;              -- CLK input
     LEDS:      Out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0):= "11111"); -- initialise output
End REG_LED;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF REG_LED IS
SIGNAL Temp:    integer range 0 to 9:= 0; -- initailise comparison signal
BEGIN

    CLK_Process:    PROCESS (CLK)   -- begin 
    BEGIN 

    if rising_edge(CLK) Then
        if Temp = 8 then
            Temp <= 0; -- State Count Reset
        else
            Temp <= Temp + 1 ; -- State Count
        End if;

    END IF;

    END PROCESS ;

    LED_PROCESS: Process (Temp) -- LED Outputs based on Temp count

    BEGIN

        Case Temp is

            When 0 =>
                LEDS <= "11111"; -- S0
            When 1 =>
                LEDS <= "00001"; -- S1
            When 2 =>
                LEDS <= "00001"; -- S2
            When 3 =>
                LEDS <= "11111"; -- S3
            When 4 =>
                LEDS <= "00000"; -- S4
            When 5 =>
                LEDS <= "11111"; -- S5
            When 6 =>
                LEDS <= "00100"; -- S6
            When 7 =>
                LEDS <= "01010"; -- S7
            When 8 =>
                LEDS <= "10001"; -- S8

            When others => 
                LEDS <= "11111"; -- Restart Sequence
        End Case;               

    End Process;
```

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the `Temp <= "XXXX";` part ?

Comment: it was intended to stop the sequence but i have since redesigned as i have re-read my original  assignment and the specs are different to what i had thought

Answer (score 1):

This code is pretty good, but here is one thing that needs attention:

You don't both these packages:

```
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

In fact, your code is only using the `std_logic_unsigned` package; it is not making use of the `numeric_std` package at all. The `std_logic_unsigned` package defines various arithmetic operators for the `std_logic_vector` type. These assume *unsigned* arithmetic, hence the name. You are making use of the `std_logic_unsigned` package in this line:

```
Temp <= Temp + 1 ;
```

For new code, you should really use the `numeric_std` package, not the `std_logic_unsigned` package. To do this, you would have to change the type of `Temp` to `unsigned`. Type `unsigned` is just an array of `std_logic` like `std_logic_vector`, but as its name implies, it is used to implement unsigned arithmetic.

So, I would

i) delete this line:

```
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

ii) change this line:

```
SIGNAL Temp:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0):= "0000"; -- initailise comparison signal
```

to:

```
SIGNAL Temp:   unsigned (3 downto 0):= "0000"; -- initailise comparison signal
```

iii) (as Scary Jeff points out) think about what the assignment of `Temp` to `"XXXX"` is doing. Wouldn't you prefer your counter to wrap round to `"0000"`? If, if you want it to freeze at `"1000"`, you'll need some different code. In any case, *never* put any code outside the test for the `rising_edge` of clock. (It doesn't comply with the template I showed you. What logic would you expect to be produced by this code?)

Comment: this was the code before i modified it even more last night i realised there were still a few bugs during simulation so changed it to this

Comment: i had misread my assignment i thought it asked for the sequence to finish at the 8th clock pulse but it did in fact start a continuous sequence to iamended the code to fit the specs