# VHDL Syntax error with if then process

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps is

    generic
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8
    
    );

    port 
    (
        clk          : in std_logic;
        enable       : in std_logic;
        sr_one       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_two       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_out       : out std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0)
    );

end entity ;

architecture rtl of basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps is

    
    signal sig_out  :std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    variable count  : integer := 0;
    variable count1 : integer := 0;
    
begin
    
    process (clk,enable,sr_one,sr_two,sig_out)
    
    begin
    
        if(enable = '0' or count = 16) then 
            count := 0;
            count1 := 0;
        else if (clk'event and clk='1') then
            sig_out(count) <= sr_one(count1);
            
            count := count + 1;
        
        else --if (clk'event and clk='0') then--
            sig_out(count) <= sr_two(count1);
            count := count + 1;
            
        end if;
        
        count1 := count1 + 1;   
        
        
(54)    end process;

    sr_out <= sig_out;

(58) end rtl;
```

errors:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at teste.vhd(54) near text "process";  expecting "if"
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at teste.vhd(58) near text "rtl";  expecting "if"

Comment: It's complaining about a missing "end if". My guess is you don't have a VHDL syntax guide handy so you guessed how o spell "elsif" and missed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your second if statement

```
if (clk'event and clk='1') then
```

has no `end if` associated with it. So, when the compiler gets to line 54, it encounters an `end process` before the `end if` it was expecting. Instead of this

```
if(enable = '0' or count = 16) then 
    count := 0;
    count1 := 0;
else if (clk'event and clk='1') then
    sig_out(count) <= sr_one(count1);

    count := count + 1;

else --if (clk'event and clk='0') then--
    sig_out(count) <= sr_two(count1);
    count := count + 1;

end if;
```

do this:

```
if(enable = '0' or count = 16) then 
    count := 0;
    count1 := 0;
else
    if (clk'event and clk='1') then
        sig_out(count) <= sr_one(count1);
        count := count + 1;
    else --if (clk'event and clk='0') then--
        sig_out(count) <= sr_two(count1);
        count := count + 1;
    end if;
end if;
```

However, if you are intending to synthesis this, your syntax error is the least of your worries. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539962/errorxst827-signal-count-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description/36543625#36543625).

Comment: @MatheusSasso As I said, you need to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539962/errorxst827-signal-count-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description/36543625#36543625). You have describe behaviour that is not synthesisable. A logic synthesiser's job is to think of a circuit that behaves like you code. It cannot do this. Nor can I. You have described behaviour that cannot be implemented using combinational logic and D-type flip-flops. The error messages in your other question tell you what this behaviour is. So, you need to change your code as in the link I posted.