# Synchronous Register design VHDL

Tags: vhdl, quartus

How do I make this `register` design synchronous?

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;

ENTITY register1 IS
  PORT (
    d_in : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
    load : IN std_logic;
    clear : IN std_logic;
    reg1 : INOUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END register1;

ARCHITECTURE toplevel OF register1 IS
BEGIN
  PROCESS (load, clear)
  BEGIN
    IF clear = '1' THEN
      reg1 <= "00000000";
    ELSIF load = '1' THEN
      reg1 <= d_in;
    ELSIF load = '0' THEN
      reg1 <= reg1;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE toplevel;
```

Comment: See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539962/errorxst827-signal-count-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description/36543625#36543625).

Comment: You code is missing `d_in` from the sensitivity list. It also describes a latch

Comment: You clock it...

Answer (score 1):

To have a synchronous design you need to add a clock you want to sync to and then perform your logic e.g. on the rising edge

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;

ENTITY register1 IS
  PORT (
    clk_i : IN std_logic;
    d_in : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
    load : IN std_logic;
    clear : IN std_logic;
    reg1 : INOUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END register1;

ARCHITECTURE toplevel OF register1 IS
BEGIN
  PROCESS (clk_i, clear) -- Note the change of the sensitivity list
  BEGIN
    IF clear = '1' THEN
      reg1 <= "00000000";
    ELSIF rising_edge(clk_i) THEN
      IF load = '1' THEN
        reg1 <= d_in;
      ELSE
        reg1 <= reg1;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE toplevel;
```

Note that this still is async `clear`.
Btw. why is `reg1` of type `INOUT`?

Comment: `ELSE reg1 <= reg1;`: this code is redundant. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: I know it is, but some people prefer to have it there anyway