# 10028 Can't solve multiple constant drivers for net "D[x]"

Tags: vhdl

Hi pleople this is my code, and the only error is Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "D[22]" at bonus2.vhd(26). I<m new at this and I don't understant this error.
Here is my code

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bonus2 is 
    port (
           B,C        : in unsigned(15 downto 0);
           clear, clk : in std_logic;
           Q          : out unsigned(31 downto 0)
             );
end entity bonus2;

architecture arch_bonus2 of bonus2 is
        signal mult : unsigned(31 downto 0); --signal d'addition
        signal D:     unsigned(31 downto 0); --signal d'addition
        begin
            mult <= B * C;
            process(clear) 
            begin
                    if clear = '1'  then        
                        D <= x"00000000";
                    end if;
                    end process;
            process(clk)
                begin
                    if rising_edge(clk) then
                        D <= mult + D;
                    end if;
            end process;
Q <= D;
end architecture arch_bonus2;
```

Comment: The message is perfectly clear : signal "D" is driven from more than one process. You usually don't want to do that.

Comment: You've got a short circuit. You have two processes driving the `D` signal. See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539962/errorxst827-signal-count-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description/36543625#36543625) after starting after "Basically, you need to refactor your code. "

Comment: There are 19 up voted answer vhdl tagged questions on this error and Matthew Taylor has provided at least two of those that can be described as duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows that you might be unfamiliar with some concepts of hardware design, so I suggest you catch up on combinational/sequential logic and how to describe them with VHDL. Also, a good rule of thumb is that you should be able to draw some parts of your design, and if you do you'll see that the `D` wire is driven by multiple nets.

What I believe you want to do, based on your code, is to be able to reset/initialize your output register. However, the way you have coded it suggests you want an **asynchronous** reset.

Please check [here](https://allaboutfpga.com/synchronous-asynchronous-reset-vhdl/) to know more about synch vs asynch logic and then I suggest you to explore further to understand the [implications](https://www.embedded.com/asynchronous-reset-synchronization-and-distribution-challenges-and-solutions/).

Here is a modified version of your code with an **asynchronous** reset, because it seems what you want.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bonus2 is 
    port (
           B,C        : in unsigned(15 downto 0);
           clear, clk : in std_logic;
           Q          : out unsigned(31 downto 0)
             );
end entity bonus2;

architecture arch_bonus2 of bonus2 is
        signal mult : unsigned(31 downto 0); --signal d'addition
        signal D:     unsigned(31 downto 0); --signal d'addition
        begin
            mult <= B * C;
            process(clk,clear)
                    if clear == '1' then
                        D <= x"00000000";
                    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                        D <= mult + D;
                    end if;
            end process;
            Q <= D;
end architecture arch_bonus2;
```

Comment: no, because I also provided a fixed version of their code

Comment: You provide no answer to "...and I don't understant this error. "

Comment: "Also, a good rule of thumb is that you should be able to draw some parts of your design, and if you do you'll see that the D wire is driven by multiple nets."

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update "A _net_ is a collection of drivers, signals (including ports and implicit signals), conversion functions, and resolution functions that, taken together, determine the effective and driving values of every signal on the net." You conflate nets and drivers as well as nets and wires. Address why a Quartus synthesis tool might object to having multiple _constant_ drivers (it's not a VHDL language error for resolved types and VHDL doesn't have wires as a class of objects).